# Unable to authenticate magento Api(V2) Using C#. Always facing these error "Session expired. Try to re login."

Tags: c#, api, magento

I am trying to download order from web server using magento soap API(v2). but i am unable to authenticate with magento web server.
I have removed all service reference  and reinstalled service reference like "http://example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl" but facing same issue "Session expired. Try to re login.". 
Also I have created new project and run the same code. Then i have successfully authenticate with magento website with magento API(V2)
and return session id.
Also I have cleaned the whole solution and build it, Then facing same issue "Session expired. Try to re login.".
My code snepad are given bellow

```
try
            {
_apiUrl = magento.MagentoHostName + "/index.php/api/v2_soap/index";
  userName = magento.MagentoUserName;
   apiKey = magento.MagentoApiKey;

 string endpointURL = _apiUrl;
 string endpointConfigurationName = "Port";
  MagentoService.PortTypeClient service = new MagentoService.PortTypeClient();

var session = service.login(userName, apiKey);
 }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                r = ErrorHandler.CustomizeError(e, r);
            }
```

Comment: all I can help is, what I understand is that session expired timeout can be set larger. also if base url changes then session is destroyed or expired.

Comment: If i used same base URL which i have used in service reference then i am facing same error "Session expired. Try to re login.”.Also I have created new project and run the same code. Then i have successfully authenticate with magento website with magento API(V2) and return session id.